# how to get all the languages array in yii1?

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x

the directory structure is like this

```
modules/
       /module1
              /messages/
                       /en
                          /admin.php
                          /profile.php
                       /ru/
                          /admin.php
                          /profile.php

       /module2/
              /messages/
                       /en
                          /account.php
                          /stats.php
                       /ru
                          /account.php
                          /stats.php
```

each of thos php files has a huge array inside where by the array contains a key value pair of the text strings like e.g

```
return array(
'hello' => 'aloha'
);
```

so how to get the arrays in each files ?

Comment: You aim to get all arrays inside all those files ? or a specific language ?

Comment: ok for example the english (en) ..how to get the arrays from each of the files under the en directory ?

Comment: you mean this? http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/638/simple-example-for-language-translation/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you may implement new method to achieve this using [`glob()`](http://php.net/glob) php function

```
$language = 'en';

foreach (glob('modules/*/messages/' . $language . '/*') as $file) {
    echo "$file\n";
}
```

Output :

```
modules/module1/messages/en/admin.php
modules/module1/messages/en/profile.php
modules/module2/messages/en/admin.php
modules/module2/messages/en/profile.php
```

to return arrays from inside those files :

```
$language = 'en';
$arrays = [];
foreach (glob('modules/*/messages/' . $language . '/*') as $file) {
    $arrays[] = require_once "$file";
}

print_r($arrays);
```

Comment: then how you get the arrays from each of those files ?

Comment: is there a way also to get the e.g en, ru, ch, jp ..because those abbreviations are names of directories inside the messages directory...i want to know also how many languages are available inside the messages directory

Comment: you need to get count of en,ru,ch.... ? or need to generally get your all data from all messages dirs ?

Comment: basically i just need to get all the messages of each languages

Comment: use this pattern inside glob instead `'modules/*/messages/*/*'`

Comment: when you assigned the $file the empty array,it's not reading the actual arrays inside each files right?..you just assigned the file names

Comment: you need to return your arrays from your languages files , in the latest example I've included the files using `require_once`